# How to run contract verification on a filtered transaction?

Tags: corda

Assume a node is given a filtered transaction containing a few states, while some have been excluded out. How can the node run the smart contract verify function on the states that included in the transaction? Am trying to achieve something similar to `ledgerTransaction.verify()`

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3, you cannot run the remaining states' `verify` methods, since the `verify` method requires a `LedgerTransaction`.

Instead, you would have to retrieve the states from the `FilteredTransaction`, and provide your own checking logic. For example:

```
val inputStateRefs = filteredTransaction.inputs

val inputStateAndRefs = inputStateRefs.map { inputStateRef -> 
    serviceHub.toStateAndRef<TemplateState>(inputStateRef) 
}

inputStateAndRefs.forEach { inputStateAndRef ->
    val state = inputStateAndRef.state
    // TODO: Checking...
}
```